# Missing refactor fields in QGIS 2.18.13

Tags: qgis-processing

I have installed QGIS 2.18.13 "Las Palmas" and I wanted to edit a table using refactor fields. I search the item using Processing toolbox/Geoalgorithms/Vector/Table tools, and the refactor fields is missing.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: For which platform are you using? Are you using the latest QGIS 2.18.13-1 version?